# Jersey 2.27, spring 5.0.7.RELEASE and Java 10 compliance issue

Tags: spring, jersey-2.0, java-10

I think I have a compliance issue. I am getting this exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.getProvider(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:202)
at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.<clinit>(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:45)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ClassConstants.<clinit>(ClassConstants.java:64)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.AbstractIdentityMap.getDefaultIdentityMapClass(AbstractIdentityMap.java:339)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.<init>(Project.java:109)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:230)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:186)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1140)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:193)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:325)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:345)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.isReadable(MOXyJsonProvider.java:470)
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.internal.ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.isReadable(ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.java:189)
```

The nullpointer is here:

```
//try this on JDK 8+ only (see bug 464096)
if (!useJ2SE7IndirectCollections && JavaSEPlatform.CURRENT.atLeast(JavaSEPlatform.v1_8)) {
```

because JavaSEPlatform.CURRENT is null with Java 10 (see the enum below):

```
/** Java SE 1.1. */
v1_1(1,1),
/** Java SE 1.2. */
v1_2(1,2),
/** Java SE 1.3. */
v1_3(1,3),
/** Java SE 1.4. */
v1_4(1,4),
/** Java SE 1.5. */
v1_5(1,5),
/** Java SE 1.6. */
v1_6(1,6),
/** Java SE 1.7. */
v1_7(1,7),
/** Java SE 1.8. */
v1_8(1,8),
/** Java SE 9. */
v1_9(1,9),
/** Java SE 9. */
v9_0(9, 0);
```

Can someone confirm that this is a bug? I cannot report the bug as this https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues is read-only.
What fix can I apply (except downgrading to java 9)?

Thanks for replies.

**Edit**
Jersey version is 2.27, not 2.17 as I first wrote

Comment: This is the current repository: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey

Comment: The release of Jersey you are using (2.17) is over three years old. Rather than downgrading Java, it might be worth trying [the latest release of Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/download.html) (2.27) first if that is possible. There was an unrelated Java 10 issue [_Java 10 compiled class is breaking at the startup_](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3799) which was fixed in Release 2.27.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I mis written the jersey version: I already use 2.27, I update the post

Comment: I added issue in the current repo https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3874

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the repo, I updated the pom.xml file with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Not Java 10 compliant -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the npe disappeared

Comment: This helped me to solve very similar exception with jaxws-ri 2.3.0, JavaSEPlatform.CURRENT inside org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink is null on JDK 11. Updating this particular dependency to 2.7.4, and excluding it from jaxws-ri fixes the issue. Posting in case anyone encounters similar issue.